# I can't connect button to @IBAction

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm  stuck after attempt to connect button to `IBAction`. Could you help, please? It doesn't show me any possibility to connect:

[image: (picture linked)]

here goes the function of my `@IBAction`

[image: (picture linked)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select `view controller` on the storyboard then check on the right is custom class set to your view controller!

First select:

[image: Image 1]

Then check on right.

[image]